# How to fetch image from django FileResponse using javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to render an image in html using javascript, and the image is being retrieved from a django view using the fetch api. I think I am close but can't figure out how to display image in browser using javascript.

**view #1:** (url: builds/imgretrieve/int:device/)

```
class imgRetrieve(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        device = self.kwargs['device']
        deviceVals = CustomUser.objects.get(id=device)
        buildImg = ImageRequest.objects.filter(author = deviceVals).latest("dateAdded")
        return FileResponse(buildImg.image)
```

When I access this view directly using a browser, it displays an image as expected.

However when I want the javascript to display it in a different view, it just displays [object Response] instead of the image.
Here is how I am attempting to do this:

**view #2** (url: builds/chamberCam/int:device/)

```
class chamberCamView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chamberCam.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        device = self.kwargs['device']
        deviceVals = CustomUser.objects.get(id=device)
        CustomUser.objects.filter(id = device).update(imgRequested = True, imgReceived = False,)
        context['deviceName'] = deviceVals.UserDefinedEquipName
        context['deviceID'] = deviceVals.id
        return context
```

**html**

```
{% block body %}
<p hidden id = "id">{{ deviceID }}</p>
<div class="">Chamber cam for {{deviceName}}</div>
<div class="imageDiv" id = "image">
</div>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'camera/chamberCam.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**chamberCam.js**

```
let deviceID = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
getImg(deviceID)
function getImg(deviceID){
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/builds/imgretrieve/' + deviceID + '/')
    .then(function(res){
      return res;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      let image = document.getElementById("image");
      console.log(data)
        image.innerHTML = `
        <img>${data}</img>
        `;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was over complicating it..
I replaced the javascript code with:

```
let deviceID = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
addimage(deviceID)

function addimage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/builds/imgretrieve/' + deviceID + '/'
    image.appendChild(img);
}
```